# Any way to make mysql not freeze my computer?

Tags: mysql

I wrote a script to insert around 10gb worth of data into the test server running in localhost. Initially I inserted them one by one but that would have taken several weeks, then I started inserting them 1000 at a time async (in the same INSERT INTO command) and while the time estimate is much better(just a few hours), it constantly freezes up the computer and sometimes I wonder if the whole system crashed.

Mysql is running as a service and is installed as a part of the xampp package. How could I throttle it just enough so it wouldn't freeze my computer while still running as fast as possible?

Comment: What are your server's specs? An SSD helps a ton, as does lots of fast RAM. Have you tried batching in separate `INSERT` commands instead? On such a large dataset the receiving table's indexing structure may also affect `INSERT`s.

Comment: 6 core ivy bridge xeon @ 2.4ghz, 64gb ram, 480GB Intel SSD that the sql database and the file I'm importing from is on. I think its the SSD thats choking up, the cpu and ram use are trivial according to the task manager.

Answer (score 0):

It could help to delete all the indexes before the bulk insert and re-create them after it is done.